# How to select 3 records before x ID and 5 records after x ID with Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, php

How can I select 3 records before x ID and 5 records after x ID with Laravel Eloquent or mysql?

Answer (score 1):

(" or mysql")

```
( SELECT ... FROM ...
        WHERE id < x ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... FROM ...
        WHERE id > x ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5 )
ORDER BY id   -- optional
```

If you want to include `id=x`, then change `<` to `<=` *or* `>` to `>=`.

How to turn that into Laravel?  I don't know.  Maybe you will need something clumsier.